# Correlated Noise

Tags: noise, correlation

I have a vector of samples $Y[n]$.

Then a fraction of delayed version of this vector added to itself:

$$Y_\text{noisy}[n] = Y[n]+ aY[n-m]$$

The term $Y[n-m]$ considered as a correlated noise. How can I construct the original $Y[n]$ from $Y_\text{noisy}[n]$?

Comment: do you know $a$ or $m$?

Comment: No I wont have the values.

Answer (score 1):

> The term $Y[n−m]$ considered as a correlated noise.

Let's consider that term just as delayed version of your signal, for the moment:

$$Y_\text{noisy}[n] = Y[n]+ aY[n-m]$$

says that $Y_\text{noisy}$ is actually $Y$, but after being subjected to the linear, non-recursive system with the $z$-transform

$$H(z) = 1 + a z^{-m}$$

This $H$ is something that is what we'd call a *FIR filter*, often. The point here is that for values of $a\ne0 $, your system isn't an all-pass – it attenuates, even "deletes" certain spectral components of your $Y$.

For example, let $\tilde Y$ be harmonic, and have $2m$ period. That implies that $\tilde Y[n - m]=-\tilde Y[n]$. For $a=1$ this means you have no chance of reconstructing that:

$$\tilde Y_\text{noisy}[n] = \tilde Y[n] + 1\tilde Y[n-m] = \tilde Y[n]-\tilde Y[n] = 0$$

So, you've built a frequency-selective system. You can, by finding a polynomial that has poles where your $H(z)$ has zeros, however, make an allpass out of your system and eliminate (aside from these points in $z$) the effect.

Comment: Thank you. Does Signal Whitening work in this case. I read that to cancel correlated noise de-correlation and whitening method can be used and I consider the delayed signal as highly correlated noise. Am I right?

Comment: big question! Well, first of all, you can whiten the info symbols you put into your modulator and pulse shaper, but you can't whiten away the spectral shapes of these, if your system happens to have such. Then, any reasonable source coding will already whiten your data. Then there's channel coding, which you'll probably do, anyways. So, however, the usual way to deal with that is really to compensate this "filter effect" by having an equalizer.

Comment: The **_Y_noisy_ [_n_]** is used as measured data to solve Least Square and obtain model parameters. The LS won't perform well under this condition (having correlated noise). Any suggestion to replace the LS?

Comment: wasn't my recommendation to compensate for the filter effect good enough?

Comment: If I don't have information about the amplitude and shift can I still use the filtering method?

Comment: Since you know you're dealing with a very strictly defined fir filter, just estimating these values based in cross-correlation should pose no problem to you, indeed.